# Python web scraping table using selenium

Tags: python, html, css

I just got on webscraping for a personal project on my company and until now have been ok, I'm trying to get the text from this table for only the lines with red dot.

I put the link from the source code from a meraki live demo because it's need to log in to see the table that I'm talking.

Already managed to scrape the page using selenium and go where I want, I just can't get only the data from the lines with red dot.

The red dots that I trying to filter:

img style="margin-bottom:1px" src="/images/bubble-shadow-red.png" height="20px" width="20px"

In the code I just manage to get examples with the green dots:

img style="margin-bottom:1px" src="/images/bubble-shadow-1.png" height="20px" width="20px"

Table code
https://github.com/Solomonrp/Merakicase/blob/master/Case

This all the page code: 
https://github.com/Solomonrp/Merakicase/blob/master/All%20code

[I put a picture from the table that I'm talking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy8zF.png)

Manage to get the data, but now I'm trying to get the src to filter if the picture is it green or red:

```
row_conta = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='row_0']"))
col_conta = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='row_0']/td"))
print("number of rows",row_conta)
print("number of  col", col_conta)
first = "//*[@id='row_"
second = "']/td["
third = "]"

#trying to get the src ()failling)
images = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
im = images.get_attribute('src')

n = 0
while(n <35):
  n = n+1
  m = 1
  while(m <10):
      if "red" in im: #trying to check the src
        final = first+str(n)+second+str(m)+third
        tablea = browser.find_element_by_xpath(final).text
        print(tablea) 
        m=m+1
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Comment: HI, I just manage to get the data  but don't know if this is the best way. And now I'm trying to get the src of the red dot, because it's the only way to know if is it green or red. Going to edit the post with the code I did